# Which function should be preferred where the list of items could be about 100 and speed of lookup is important

Tags: c++, search, lookup

Which version of ScreenID2Text is going to give me the best performance and code maintainability?

It cannot be assumed that the screen ID passed to the function is in the list.  The real list will contain about 100 entries.

Or some other option.  Edits to function most welcome.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>

const char* ScreenID2Text1(const int ScreenID) {
    static std::unordered_map<int, char*> screens = {
        { 1, "apple" },
        { 3, "banana" },
        { 4, "orange" },
        { 7, "date" } };

    auto search = screens.find(ScreenID);
    if (search != screens.end()) {
        return search->second;
    }
    else {
        return "unknown fruit";
    }

}

const char* ScreenID2Text2(const int ScreenID) {
    static std::map<int, char*> screens = {
        { 1, "apple" },
        { 3, "banana" },
        { 4, "orange" },
        { 7, "date" } };

    auto search = screens.find(ScreenID);
    if (search != screens.end()) {
        return search->second;
    }
    else {
        return "unknown fruit";
    }

}

const char* ScreenID2Text3(const int ScreenID) {

    struct screens {
        int id;
        const char* description;
    };

    static screens types[] = {
        { 1, "apple" },
        { 3, "banana" },
        { 4, "orange" },
        { 7, "date" } };

    int size = sizeof(types) / sizeof(types[0]);

    screens candidate;
    candidate.id = ScreenID;

    auto lower = std::lower_bound(&types[0], &types[0] + size, candidate,
        [](const screens& lhs, const screens& rhs) { return lhs.id < rhs.id; });

    if (lower != &types[0] + size && lower->id == ScreenID)
        return lower->description;
    else
        return "unknown fruit";
}

int main() {

    int tests[] = { 1,2,3 };
    int numtests = sizeof(tests) / sizeof(tests[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < numtests; ++i) {
        // unordered map
        std::cout << "Test ID" << tests[i] << " result=" << ScreenID2Text1(tests[i]) << '\n';

        // unordered map
        std::cout << "Test ID" << tests[i] << " result=" << ScreenID2Text2(tests[i]) << '\n';

        // lower_bound
        std::cout << "Test ID" << tests[i] << " result=" << ScreenID2Text3(tests[i]) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you already tried benchmarking them?

Comment: not really a question for SO - but code review since it's working.

Comment: Assuming `id`is always small, just make a vector or an array, and access the element with `vec[id]`... (put some recognizable, cheap, dummy value in "empty" cells)

Comment: Are you really sure that performance of `ScreenId2Text` matters that much to you?

Comment: @MarcGlisse the integer IDs are not contiguous.  An ID passed in may not exist in the array/vector.

Comment: not contiguous: that's why I suggested putting "unknown fruit" in the empty places. You may need an extra check `if(id>vec.size())`, but the non-contiguity is only an issue if the indices can become very large and the amount of memory wasted becomes excessive.

Answer (score 2):

Well, probably the third one, just because you don't end up hitting the memory allocator. Building a map/unordered_map *every single time you call the function* is going to take up most of the time of the first two versions. But calling `lower_bound` is likewise silly, and is going to lead to overly branchy code.

Instead, have the compiler deal with optimizing this for you:

```
const char* ScreenID2TextN(const int ScreenID) {
    switch(ScreenID)
    {
        case 1: return "apple";
        case 3: return "banana";
        case 4: return "orange";
        case 7: return "date";
        default: return "unknown fruit";
    }
}
```

I would be *extremely* surprised if any of your versions beat this one.

Comment: *"list of four items"* - *"real list will contain about 100 entries"*

Comment: @HolyBlackCat In that case those three versions might do a little better, but this one will still be best. Remember, the original methods all construct the search structure in the function. They are all O(n) at best.

Comment: Have a look at: https://embeddedgurus.com/stack-overflow/2010/04/efficient-c-tip-12-be-wary-of-switch-statements/  If integers are not contiguous could end up with an if else if chain

Comment: The map / unordered_map is declared static, so it's a one-time initialization. Not "every single time you call the function".

Comment: @peterchen Yeah, the OP edited the code after I posted this answer.

Comment: @AngusComber for another language I already encountered a switch turned into an optimized binary if-tree with inner switches (jump tables). So it probably does not differ much from a normal hashing.

Comment: @AngusComber Are you aware of a compiler which is dumb enough to turn a large switch block with sparse cases into a linear if..else if chain? Because I don't know of any offhand.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the map is fixed and known at compile time you might consider a [perfect hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) approach, and use a generator like [`gperf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/).

Of course you'll better build the map (e.g. a `std::map`, or a `std::unordered_map`, or your own one) ahead of time (perhaps in your initialization routine).

In all cases, you need to benchmark. In most cases, for only a hundred entries, performance won't matter that much (since the data is likely to sit in some L1 or L2 cache).

In your MCVE example, you could even `switch` on the screen id (see [Sneftel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48151861/841108))... And you might generate the C or C++ code of that switch...

Another approach (a bit silly, but could be made very efficient) might be to generate and [JIT-compile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) some code based upon the map. You'll then use a JIT library like [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) to generate an *efficient* function from your map. Or generate some C or C++ code at runtime (perhaps using `gperf` for that) and compile it as a plugin then [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) it.

Or, as commented by [Marc Glisse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1918193/marc-glisse), use some vector. Most other approaches above could also fit if you need a fast, reverse, mapping (between names and ids).

PS. You really need to check that the speed of your `ScreenID2Text` function matters that much for the overall performance of your entire application (*I guess it does not*).